# Asp.net Impersonation is forced enabled after deployment each time

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, jenkins, iis

I use Jenkins to deploy a asp.net core 2.1 website to Windows Server 2012 R2 IIS 8.5.
The website is not running(500.24 error) because Impersonation is true. I have to manually to disable it then the web is running again.

The issue is that every time I check in the code and deploy it by Jenkins; I found that the Impersonation is set to enabled.

One thing is that the Identity in Application Pools is "ApplicationPoolIdentity".

What is the trick of it?

Comment: Set that application pool to use no ASP.NET runtime.

Comment: @LexLi, how to set it? Any screenshot or link?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/#attributes Set managedRuntimeVersion to "".

Comment: I set .NET CLR Version as "No Managed Code". But it is still not working.@LexLi

Comment: Did you inlcude   <identity impersonate="true" /> in your project's web.config? When you publish the application, web.config get overwrite every time.

Comment: @JokiesDing If the pool is set to use No Managed Runtime, then it makes no sense that IIS/ASP.NET Core Module verifies impersonation setting (or any other `<system.web>` setting). Thus, I consider that's a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IIS XML configuration, modify the pool element as below,

1. Set `managedRuntimeVersion` as `""`.
2. Set `managedPipelineMode` as `"Classic"`

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/#attributes)

The second step shouldn't be needed, but sounds like Microsoft left a bug there.

Comment: You are right. After I added the second step, it works then. The step one is not enough.